# Microsoft Identity Framework assigning roles to user error with Postgres Database - The CancellationTokenSource has been disposed

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Hi I am having issues with assigning roles to users with Identity Framework 5.0.5, .net5.0.5 and a Postgres SQL db.

The code used to assign the roles to users can be seen below with the error below it.

Please help if possible.

Thanks so much!

```
       {
           if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin"))
           {
               await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole
               {
                   Name = "Admin"
               });
           }
           
           ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
           if (isAdmin)
           {
               await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
           }
           else
           {
               await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
           }
       }
   }


services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseNpgsql(
       Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
       builder => builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(50, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), null)));
```

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: The CancellationTokenSource has been disposed.
   at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
   at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(Int32 millisecondsDelay)
   at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan delay)
   at Npgsql.Util.ResettableCancellationTokenSource.Stop()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|40_0(NpgsqlReadBuffer buffer, Int32 count, Boolean async, Boolean readingNotifications)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at SearchDataScreening.Pages.UserManagement.OnGetAdminControl(String userId, Boolean isAdmin) in /Users/dewaldthattingh/GitHubRepos/TPS/SearchScreening/SearchDataScreening/Pages/UserManagement.cshtml.cs:line 50
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__140_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.<>c.<.cctor>b__6_0(QueueUserWorkItemCallback quwi)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunForThreadPoolUnsafe[TState](ExecutionContext executionContext, Action`1 callback, TState& state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Comment: Try to set a break point and check which line of code will throw this error? Besides, you could try to do the same action via the DbContext, instead of using UserManager and RoleManager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try changing it to not use the await methods like below

```
  bool roleExist =  roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin").Result;
        if (!roleExist)
        {
            var x =  roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole
            {
                Name = "Admin"
            }).Result;
        }

        if (isAdmin)
        {
            var user =  userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId).Result;
            if (user != null)
            {
                var x = userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin").Result;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var user =  userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId).Result;
            if (user != null)
            {
                var x = userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, "Admin").Result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you Explain Why not use the await Keyword?

Comment: I was playing around with this and this was the only way I seemed to get it to work on my side.
Using await didn't let the call finish and the project tried starting a second operation before the previous finished, the above way avoids it. 
The only thing I could think of is that the reason for this is that it's related to some issue with .net 5. Anyway this worked on my side :D

Comment: you have blocked a Method that support  Asynchronous programming , its seems it is not a best practice

Comment: I am aware of this, unfortunately, the best practice doesn't seem to work right in this case.
I am just giving the solution that I found to work